# Efficient Base64 conversion in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Im quite new on powershell so sorry for this basic question

I came across with the following script to convert a binary to base64 but Im not understanding how do I define the file input/output and I found no contact of who made this script so if someone could tell me how this works I would appreciate

The code is

```html
function ConvertTo-Base64
{
    param
    (
        [string] $SourceFilePath,
        [string] $TargetFilePath
    )
 
    $SourceFilePath = Resolve-PathSafe $SourceFilePath
    $TargetFilePath = Resolve-PathSafe $TargetFilePath
     
    $bufferSize = 9000 # should be a multiplier of 3
    $buffer = New-Object byte[] $bufferSize
     
    $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($SourceFilePath)
    $writer = [System.IO.File]::CreateText($TargetFilePath)
     
    $bytesRead = 0
    do
    {
        $bytesRead = $reader.Read($buffer, 0, $bufferSize);
        $writer.Write([Convert]::ToBase64String($buffer, 0, $bytesRead));
    } while ($bytesRead -eq $bufferSize);
     
    $reader.Dispose()
    $writer.Dispose()
}
 
function ConvertFrom-Base64
{
    param
    (
        [string] $SourceFilePath,
        [string] $TargetFilePath
    )
 
    $SourceFilePath = Resolve-PathSafe $SourceFilePath
    $TargetFilePath = Resolve-PathSafe $TargetFilePath
 
    $bufferSize = 9000 # should be a multiplier of 4
    $buffer = New-Object char[] $bufferSize
     
    $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($SourceFilePath)
    $writer = [System.IO.File]::OpenWrite($TargetFilePath)
     
    $bytesRead = 0
    do
    {
        $bytesRead = $reader.Read($buffer, 0, $bufferSize);
        $bytes = [Convert]::FromBase64CharArray($buffer, 0, $bytesRead);
        $writer.Write($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length);
    } while ($bytesRead -eq $bufferSize);
     
    $reader.Dispose()
    $writer.Dispose()
}
 
function Resolve-PathSafe
{
    param
    (
        [string] $Path
    )
      
    $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($Path)
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick response :

```
function ConvertTo-Base64
{
    param
    (
        [string] $SourceFilePath,
        [string] $TargetFilePath
    )
 ...
}
```

Discribes a function that takes two parameters, you can call it like this :

```
ConvertTo-Base64 "c:\temp\soucefile" "c:\temp\destfile"
```

Supposing that your script is in file `"c:\temp\converter.ps1"`, you can write a new script `"MyScript.ps1"` :

```
# MyScript.ps1

# Dot source external script
. "c:\temp\converter.ps1"

# use the converter
ConvertTo-Base64 "c:\temp\soucefile" "c:\temp\destfile"
```